# Problem finding a function and plotting it

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following equation `Ls j[t]/Is (1 + (RealAbs[j[t]/Is])^S)^(-1/(S + B)) = 7 Sin[2 \[Pi] 50 t]`
How can I find the variable j[t] and graph it?
Tell me what function to use to find j[t]? I tried using NSolve and NSolveValues ​​but nothing worked for me. Here's my failed solutions:

```
Ls = 0.0127; Is = 1.1; S = 3.6; B = 0.136;

NSolve[Ls j/Is (1 + (RealAbs[j/Is])^S)^(-1/(S + B)) == 
  7 Sin[2 \[Pi] 50 0.5 ], j, Reals]
sol = NSolve[
  Ls j[t]/Is (1 + (RealAbs[j[t]/Is])^S)^(-1/(S + B)) == 
   7 Sin[2 \[Pi] 50 t], j[t], Reals]
```

I understand that the solution must depend on `t`. I'm looking forward to any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ContourPlot` to show the solution `{j,t}`

```
ContourPlot[
Ls  j/Is (1 + (RealAbs[j /Is])^S)^(-1/(S + B)) ==7 Sin[2 \[Pi] 50 t]
, {t, 0, 5/50 }, {j, -10, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 3,FrameLabel -> {t, j}]
```

[image]